# How is the first step to register Audit.Net in the "Startup.cs" of my application?

Tags: audit.net

Audit.Net

SomeBody can help me with one newbie question?
How is the first step to register Audit.Net in the "Startup.cs" of my application?

I'm try do audit with Entity FrameWrok focus one single table:

[image]

**But i don't know waht is the NameSpace for this error?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That example is assuming you have an entity called `AuditLog` that is mapped to your single audit table.

[image]

You must create that entity if you don't have it already.

The table structure is up to you. You just tell the library how to map the different entities audits to your single audit entity.